# How to avoid index out of range error with current implementation?

Tags: python, for-loop

I've been given a list of integers called `nums`, and am trying to remove all occurrences of the value (`val`). I'm trying to see where `val` matches an index of `nums` and am trying to remove it from the list. However, I keep getting a "list index out of range" error. I'm guessing it is because as I am popping the element of `nums` that matches `val`, it shrinks the list so it goes out of range. Is it not possible to remove all occurrences of value in this way?

```
nums = [3,2,2,3]
val = 2
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if val == nums[i]:
        nums.pop(i)
print(nums)
```

Comment: Rule for general happiness: Do not mutate (pop) the same sequence you are iterating over.

Comment: Duplicate the list to iterate over it, then set nums to that new list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not try to remove elements from the list as you're iterating over it, as the memory is shifting as you're accessing it.

Instead, you should create a new list:

```py
nums = [3,2,2,3]
val = 2
print([num for num in nums if val != num]) # Prints [3, 3]
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that im sort of starting python to do leetcode and was trying to solve the remove all occurrences of a target number from the array in-place, but I thought I was on to something here.

Answer (score 0):

use `remove` method to remove vlaues from list

```
nums = [3,2,2,3]
val = 2
l = list(nums)#creating new list
for v in l:
    if v == val:
        nums.remove(val)#removing values

print(nums)
```

### output:

```
$ python3 file.py 
[3, 3]
```